# Verificar que la hora actual este dentro de un rango de horas Java

Tags: java

Buen dia quiero verificar que la hora actual este dentro de un rango de horas permitidas para continuar con el ingreso de un usuario, el problema que tengo es que al usar la clase Gregorian calendar no me toma bien las horas del rango permitido, tengo algunos problemas para fijar las horas, el rango esta entre las 5:00am y las 12:00 del medio dia, imprimo cada una de las horas para observar que horas esta asignando.

```
    String tipodeplan = txt_tipodeplan.getText();
    String texto = "Plan Matutino";
    boolean resultado = texto.contains(tipodeplan);

    if(resultado){            
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El usuario esta en horario matutino");
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

    cal.set(GregorianCalendar.HOUR, 5);
    cal.set(GregorianCalendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(GregorianCalendar.SECOND, 0);

    Date hora1 = cal.getTime();

    cal.set(GregorianCalendar.HOUR, 12);

    Date hora2 = cal.getTime();
    Date ahora = new Date(); 

    System.out.println(hora1);
    System.out.println(hora2);
    System.out.println(ahora);        
    if (ahora.compareTo(hora1) >= 0 && ahora.compareTo(hora2) <= 0)
    {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El usuario puede ingresar");

    } else{ 
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"El usuario esta fuera del horario matutino");

    } 


    }      

}
```

Esto es lo que imprime

```
Wed Apr 03 17:00:00 COT 2019
Thu Apr 04 00:00:00 COT 2019
Wed Apr 03 15:11:57 COT 2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambiando lo siguiente:

```
cal.set(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
cal.set(GregorianCalendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
```

Al imprimir sale lo siguiente:

```
Wed Apr 03 05:00:00 ECT 2019
Wed Apr 03 12:00:00 ECT 2019
Wed Apr 03 16:28:50 ECT 2019
```

Aqui puedes encontrar información sobre [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR)